# Family of residual representations compatible with a motive

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations

Suppose $S$ is a set of primes. For each prime $p$ in $S$ we are given a Galois representation $\rho_p : Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow GL_2 (\mathbb{F}_p) $. What are the necessary or sufficient conditions on this collection that these are residual representations associated to a motive over $\mathbb{Q}$?